# Why can a class with a @Transactional method not be autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security with a WAFFLE filter that authenticates the users against an ActiveDirectory server.
I created an additional filter that authenticates the user against my database as well (it just checks if the
previously authenticated user is in the database). This is done using an implementation of `UserDetailsService`.

This combination was working until I added an `@Transactional` annotated method to the service. Now the service
can not be autowired to the filter.

This is the service class:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LdapUserDao ldapUserDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return getUserByUsername(username);
    }

    public User getUserByUsername(final String username) {
        final User databaseUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        final User ldapUser = ldapUserDao.findByUsername(username);

        if (null == databaseUser || null == ldapUser) {
            return null;
        }

        final User user = mergeUsers(databaseUser, ldapUser);

        return user;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void storeUser(final User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    private User mergeUsers(final User database, final User ldap) {
        final User mergedUser = new User();

        mergedUser.setId(database.getId());
        mergedUser.setUsername(database.getUsername());
        mergedUser.setEnabled(database.isEnabled());
        mergedUser.setRoles(database.getRoles());

        mergedUser.setEmail(ldap.getEmail());
        mergedUser.setFirstName(ldap.getFirstName());
        mergedUser.setLastName(ldap.getLastName());
        mergedUser.setLocale(ldap.getLocale());

        return mergedUser;
    }

}
```

And this is the filter:

```
public class WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        final Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

        if (null == authentication || !(authentication instanceof WindowsAuthenticationToken)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        final WindowsAuthenticationToken waffleAuthentication = (WindowsAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        final String username = waffleAuthentication.getName().replaceAll("^.*\\\\", "");
        final User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);

        if (null == user) {
            securityContext.setAuthentication(null);
            return;
        }

        final WaffleAuthenticationWrapper authenticationWrapper = new WaffleAuthenticationWrapper(waffleAuthentication,
                user);

        securityContext.setAuthentication(authenticationWrapper);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

As soon as I remove the `@Transactional` the project compiles again. Why is it not possible to annotate the method as `@Transactional`?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at my.project.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter my.project.config.WebSecurityConfig.waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter my.project.config.WebSecurityConfig.waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter my.project.config.WebSecurityConfig.waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter my.project.config.WebSecurityConfig.waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter my.project.config.WebSecurityConfig.waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'waffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.project.services.UserService my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set my.project.services.UserService field my.project.auth.WaffleAuthenticationWrapperFilter.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:557)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Because you should be programming to interfaces (`UserDetailsService`) instead of concrete classes (`UserService`). This is due to the fact that spring uses proxies to apply AOP (and that is how transactions are applied). You get a proxy that is a `UserDetailsService` but not a `UserService` hence it cannot be injected.

Comment: @M.Deinum All right. I made an interface from the `UserService` class that extends the `UserDetailsService`. Then I moved the implementation to `UserServiceImpl` and annotated the class with `@Service`. Now everything is working again. If you write a short answer I can mark it as accepted, since you were the first to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would just create 2 interfaces instead of having 1 extend the other. But that is just personal preference :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To apply AOP spring uses proxies, these come in 2 flavors JDK Dynamic Proxies (interface based) and CgLIB based proxies (class based). By default Spring uses JDK Dynamic Proxies for classes that implement 1 or more interfaces.

At runtime you get a dynamically created object (the proxy) which implements all the interfaces (`UserDetailsService`) of the class it is wrapping (`UserService`). So that dynamically created object is a `UserDetailsService` but not a `UserService`.

Hence the error that the proxy cannot be cast to the `UserService`.

You have (at least) 2 ways of fixing this

1. Program to interfaces
2. Enable class based proxies.

### Program to interfaces

As you are calling the `getUserByUsername` you would need to create a new interface and implement this as well as the `UserDetailsService`.

```
public interface UserService {
    User getUserByUsername(String username);
    void storeUser(User user);
    List<User> findAllUsers();
}

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService { ... }
```

If you do it like this you can leave your filter untouched, as the `UserService` is now simply an interface. If you give the interface another name you would also have to change the `UserService` field in the filter to be of that type.

### Enable class based proxies

As you are using spring boot enabling class based proxies is as easy as adding a property to your `application.properties` file.

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

This will create a class based proxy and that way you can leave your code for the filter unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

Should become

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService  userService;
```

because your @Transactional proxy is not an instance of UserService but it's an instance of UserDetailService (your interface)

Comment: oops, right, i didn't catch that there WAS, in fact, an interface involved.

Answer (score 1):

as @mdeinum pointed out, native proxies in java can only proxy interfaces, not classes. this is also best practice. so you would have to do:

```
@Autowired
private IUserService userService;
```

and then

```
public class UserService implements IUserService
```

however, there are cases (especially with AOP) where it isn't possible. if that's the case you can use cglib proxies instead of native java proxies. you would have to add this to your (maven?) dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and tell spring-aop to proxy classes:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Comment: Newer versions of spring use a repackaged glib version so you don't need to add it anymore.

Comment: Since spring 3.2... See also http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html