# Object null after get bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a dao object and inside the dao object I have the following code:
When I get the bean MyDao the object is null. If I remove the @Transient annotation, it works but then fails on the updateUser because it says transactionRequiredException. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

```
@Service
public abstract class MyDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {
    protected Integer batchSize;

    public Integer getBatchSize() {
        return batchSize;
    }
    public void setBatchSize(Integer batchSize) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
    }

    @Transient
    public void updateUser() {
        String deleteHQL = "delete from users";
        this.getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(); 

    }

}
```

Bean:

```
<bean id="myDao" name="dao" class="com.project.MyDao">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <property name="batchSize" value="5000" />
</bean>
```

I annotated the class with @Service, @Component and the object is still null as long as @Transactional is on that method.
I ran this in debug mode to see if the getters/setters are being called and they are, the object is just returning null properties though as shown here:
[image]

EDIT:
When I call TextDao testDao = (TestDao) myContext.getBean("testDao"); with @Transactional, I see this:

[image]

without @Transactional I see this:

[image]

When I create the dao object, the constructor and the setters do not call updateNames. This is the issue I am having and I am not too sure what the issue is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can a class with a @Transactional method not be autowired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344084/why-can-a-class-with-a-transactional-method-not-be-autowired)

Comment: Try autowiring this class in `@Service` class, and then annotate appropiate method with `@Transactional`

Comment: @Dargenn I tried adding `@Service` on the class and the object is still null.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong object. This the proxy wrapping the actual,object instance. So the actual field isn’t null. Also why is it a scoped proxy?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have other fields in there like batchSize and it is null inside the object. When I remove `@Transactional`, the batch size is populated with 5000.

Comment: Again, those aren't `null` on the actual object as you are looking at the proxy NOT the actual object.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the post above to clearly state the issue I am having.

Comment: And again I'm stating you are looking at the proxy which will have those as `null`. You should be looking at the actual instance and NOT the proxy. There is no issue, as you are looking at the "wrong" object.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand what your saying the issue is but I don't see how I am looking at the proxy object since I am looking at where I am declaring the object. Could you either give me a small example or explain where the non-proxy object is?

Comment: Spring uses AOP to add transactions to your object. To do so it creates a proxy (a wrapper for th actual object) that adds that behavior. The actual target bean is in one of those interceptors you see, they are more or less a chain.